# Searching only in undeleted documents using zend lucene

Tags: search, zend-lucene

I am not new with zend lucene but I have a trouble with searching using it.
**I search in documents by numbers using below code:**

```
$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($id, $idFieldName);
$docIds  = $index->termDocs($term);
foreach ($docIds as $id) {
    $doc = $index->getDocument($id);
    echo $doc->artist_name;
}
$index->commit();
```

**and deleting a document by number using below code:**

```
$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($id, $idFieldName);
$docIds  = $index->termDocs($term);
foreach ($docIds as $id) {

    $doc = $index->getDocument($id);
    $index->delete($doc->lyric_id);

}
$index->commit();
```

When I delete a document, `$index->numDocs()` display that the document is deleted because the returned value is not equals the returned value of `$index->count()`. but the problem is, after deleting the document, I can search in it yet and I can display the value of its fields.

I checked that after optimizing the indexes but the problem is live yet. I need to remove completely a document or search in the documents that are not deleted from indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the search results and check if the document is deleted. If it is, remove it from the search results.

> Zend_Search_Lucene::isDeleted($id) method may be used to check if a
>   document is deleted.
>
> ```
> for ($count = 0; $count < $index->maxDoc(); $count++) {
> if ($index->isDeleted($count)) {
>     echo "Document #$id is deleted.\n";
> } }
> ```

via [Building Indexes: Updating Documents](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.document-updating)